# pass multiple columns into udf pyspark

Tags: pyspark, duplicates, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a function that will accept any number of DF columns and return if it contains duplicates or not.

something like that:

```
def find_duplicates(df, *args):
  df \
    .groupby([args]) \
    .count() \
    .where('count > 1') \
    .sort('count', ascending=False) \
    .show()
```

So I want to call the function using some DataFrame name and list the columns

```
find_duplicates(df, 'col', 'col2', 'col3')
```

is there any simple way?

Comment: you can pass a list in `groupBy`. so, your input to the function can just be a list of column names

Comment: Is there any problem with the current way you're doing it ?

Comment: I changed the code a little bit following and it works now. your answer helped, thanks!

Comment: def find_duplicates(df, cols):
  df \
    .groupby(cols) \
    .count() \
    .where('count > 1') \
    .sort('count', ascending=False) \
    .show()